# Perform some action on each element of an array but in small portions using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how to perform some action on each element of an array, but by working in portions of that array, until each element has been touched.

As a more specific example, let's assume I have an array of 990 elements and want to perform some action on each element, but in portions of 200. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

```
function foo(array) {
    results = []
    if (array.length > 200) {
        // Loop over and perform action on first 200 elements, then next 200, and so on...
        // for each element, push result to results array
    }

    return results;
}
```

**EDIT:**

For my specific use case, each element in the array is a URL. I'm making a GET request with each URL using Axios. There is potential for my array to contain thousands of URLs, so I don't want to make a request and wait for a response one at a time; however, the server I'm making the requests to can only handle so many requests at one time (about 200).

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you hope to accomplish? Ultimately you'll have to process every element anyway.

Comment: `arr.slice(0, 200).forEach(...)` Grab first `200` elements and then using `forEach` you can perform task.

Comment: ```for(let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(array.length/200); i++) { for(let j = i*200; j < (i+1)*100; j++) { } }``` I think this will work, though you have to calculate the extra elements that don't add up to 200

Comment: @decpk that would result in a lot more work, because `.slice()` makes a **new** array, copying values from the source array. Thus that fails the "most efficient" requirement in the question.

Comment: @UnidentifiedX it's `Math.ceil()`

Comment: @Pointy For my use case, each element in the array is a URL. I'm making a GET request with each URL using Axios. There is potential for my array to contain thousands of URLs, so I don't want to make a request and wait for a response one at at time; however, the server I'm making the requests to can only handle so many requests at one time (about 200).

Comment: @GriffsAccount OK, well next time include that kind of *extremely important* information in your question.

Comment: You're also going to have a problem structuring the process as described in your question, because your `results` array is going to be built by *asynchronous* activity, so you cannot make a synchronous-acting function.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for pointing that out, my brain thought it was roof for some reason...

Comment: @Pointy Updated my post and comment to reflect my specific use case. I felt it wasn't important as what I'm trying to do for each element doesn't change how I would expect to iterate over the array.

Comment: @Pointy Also, in creating an array of promises using Axios, the results array will return in the same order as the initial array. I just need the ability to iterate over 200 elements at a time. The rest I can handle. The function I'm trying to perform does not matter here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may not be the most efficient solution per my initial request, I found the following to be easy-to-understand:

```
while (array.length != 0) {
    array.splice(0, 200).forEach(function (url) {
        // Perform some action
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. Some ways better than others. But I will assume you dont want to modify the original array and want to handle 200 elements on different moments:

```
function stepArray(arr){
   //... create your custom index on the array object
   //..., so it will know where to continue from
   if(typeof arr.myIndex == 'undefined'){ arr.myIndex = 0; }

   for(var k=0; k<200; k++){
      if(k + arr.myIndex >= arr.length){return;}
      process(arr[k + arr.myIndex]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Modifying the original array isn't a big deal to me. Just want to be able to iterate over up to 200 elements at a time. For example. If the total size of the array is 990, I'd want to be able to iterative over the first 200, the next 200, the next 200, the next 200, then the last 190.

Answer (score 0):

To make multiple chunks you can use reduce, like that:

```
var perChunk = 200 // chunk size

var inputArray = [] // your array

const result = inputArray.reduce((resultArray, item, index) => { 
  const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index/perChunk)

  if(!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
    resultArray[chunkIndex] = [] // new chunk
  }

  resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item)

  return resultArray
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Then you can iterate again over the sible chunks a make your axios request.

```
for(i=0; i< result.length; i++) {
  let delay = 3000 * i
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(// your action with the Array arr[i])
  }, delay)
}
```